# How do I link a featured photo to it's post?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, links, featured-post

I cannot change the url of the photo in the featured-image edit section. The page can be found at https://irregularus.com/tips-and-stories/ and if you click on the picture you will see that it just opens the picture.

Comment: You will need to override the post template (template-tags.php in your case) in child theme or you can use wp_get_attachment_image_src filter to override the url

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
```

to get the link to the current post. Essentially replace whatever the href property of the image link is right now so it looks similar to :

```
<a class="post-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
```

Comment: I apologize. I'm new with this and dont quite know what that means. where do I use <?php the_permalink(); ?> and how?

Comment: You will need to edit your theme in order to apply this change - essentially editing a php file. This will be quite tricky if you've never worked with html/php/css.